# AJAX post data not parsed correctly

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm having trouble posting data to my Razor Pages page handler using an AJAX post.

```
var $container = $('.railcars');
var $rows = $container.children('.row');
var sources = [];   //data = { storage = [], railcars = [] };
for (var i = 0; i < $rows.length; i++) {
    var $sourceType = $($rows[i]).find('.source-type input');
    sources.push({
        isStorage: $sourceType.prop('checked'),
        source: $($rows[i]).find('.source-number').val(),
        volume: 0,
        markAsEmpty: false });
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '?handler=CheckNegativeWeights',
    data: JSON.stringify(sources),
    headers: {
        "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
})
.done(function (response) {
    // ...
})
.fail(function (response) {
    // ...
})
```

My handler gets an empty collection.

[image]

I can see the data is there, but apparently it isn't in the correct format.

[image]

Can someone see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are serializing the data to JSON. Handler methods cannot parse that without some help. Specifically, you need to set the content type of the request to `application/json`, and tell the handler method that the data is in the body of the request using the `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '?handler=CheckNegativeWeights',
    data: JSON.stringify(sources),
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
})
```

And

```
public async Task<IActionResult>OnPostCheckNegativeWeights([FromBody]YourModel model)
```

Comment: D'oh! I knew about `[FromBody]` but forgot all about it because my AJAX calls are almost always `GET`. That's why I couldn't figure it out. Many thanks!